# Dynamically Query like a return type function

Tags: php, jquery, database

Dynamically Query like a return type function can we use dynamically function like a dynamically return type function in my programming area is this possible

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Querys</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
public function fun($table){
 $query="SELECT * FROM ".$table;
 return $query;

}
echo fun("student");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you want? Are you want to return SQL or the result of it?.

Comment: `$query` is just a string, do you want the result or SQL? Also no relation to jquery I can see

Comment: @Ibnelaiq i want a dynamically database query function for insert, fetch, delete and update data

Comment: As @imraniqbal answered do you need to create a method for fetching and delete. I would help you

Comment: @YasirMehmood do you need fetching and delete functions

Comment: @Ibnelaiq yes i need fetching & delete functions

Comment: okay then give me some time, I am sure that I will help you

Comment: @Ibnelaiq can u send me my email ?

Comment: why not? send your email

Comment: Added the deleting method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this

```
function insert_data($table,$data){
    $sql ="INSERT INTO ".$table;
    $sql .=" (".implode(",",array_keys($data)).") VALUES";
    $sql .=" ('".implode("','", array_values($data))."')";
    $query=$conn->query($sql);
    if ($query) {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    $query->close();
}
```

Call upper function for insert the data into table. hope this will solve your issue

```
$data=array('name' => "Yasir", 'age' => 25, 'education' => "Master");
$fet=insert_data("student",$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want the deleting method, there it is:

```
   function insert_data($table,$columnName,$matchingWord){
       if($columnName == null && $matching == null || $columnName == '' && $matching == ''){
          $sql= "DELETE FROM".$columnName." WHERE 1";
       }
       else{
          $sql = "DELETE FROM".$columnName."WHERE".$columnName."=".$matchingWord."";
       }
       $query=$conn->query($sql);
       if ($query) {
            return true;
       }
       else{
            return false;
       }
        $query->close();
    }
```

call upper function just like this.

```
  insert_data("users","id","3");
```

It will delete the user where the id is equals to 3.
And if you will not give `$columnName` & `$matchinWord` it will automatically truncate the table.